# Gambling in video games?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

So this video game i know has these packs. You can either buy them, or earn them by playing the game, you get it nearly every level, sometimes you dont, but it’ll show if you will get it or not. From those packs you are always guaranteed a specific thing plus other things, but  you most likely want that specific thing, and you dont get an advantage from these packs, its cosmetic only. The difference is, that thing, it varies from tiers, but you will get it no matter what. Is this gambling since this is what i want?